# React Native Android app not working with IPv6 routers

Tags: android, react-native, android-wifi

I have a React Native Android app that is published on the Google Play store.

A number of our Android users have an issue where our app doesn't get past the splash screen (which makes a few API calls) when connected to WiFi. When we ask these users to switch to mobile data the app works flawlessly for them. All affected users I was able to speak to are only having this issue with our app, and not other apps on their devices.

I found a number of Android users have posted the same issue with other apps  and while their device, OS, and affected apps all differed the solution was uniform - disable IPv6 in their router settings.

I do not have access to an IPv6 enabled router to test this myself. I did connect my macbook via ethernet, turn on NAT64 and enable WiFi sharing, my iPhone connects perfectly, my Android devices (Nexus 5X, Nokia 8) connect with the message "Connected, no internet".

Does anyone have any experience on this?

Comment: Hello Carlos, did you found a solution for this problem? I have the same problem and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Some android devices that don't have ipv6 connection will be delayed initiating network connection when connecting to ipv6 hosts, by updating to okhttp 5.x, overriding okhttp 4.x (which is currently supported use default in react native app - react native version 0.71) will solve this problem.

Add below dependencies to `android/app/build.gradle` to force use okhttp 5.0.0-alpha.11

```
dependencies {
  // others dependencies

  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.11'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:5.0.0-alpha.11'
}
```

It works ok on android device missing ipv6
View more okttp version at: https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/changelog/ or https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp

Comment: Question is about React Native, not android native